Unexpected behavior when accessing columns of a pandas DataFrame
I am comparing the output of accessing a pandas DataFrame via iloc[] vs dot notation (e.g. df.column1). The results are unexpected...
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns=['one', 'two'])

df.iloc[:,0] is df.one

Unexpectedly, this code returns:
False

Even after assignment, df.one = df.iloc[:,0], the code df.iloc[:0] is df.one returns False
I presume one of these accessing methods is producing a copy but I have failed to find evidence in the docs or on form pages. I have done similar tests with bracket notation and the same output was produced.

What is your goal exactly? Why did you use is in the first place?

I am trying to understand why these two ways of referencing a DataFrame column, do not reference the same object.

You shouldn't use is to compare Series. First because the objects are not necessarily the same, second because even if there is only one item, if you perform an element-wise comparison, you have to aggregate the output to a scalar.
Use numpy.isclose:
np.allclose(df.iloc[:,0], df.one)

Or element-wise comparison and all:
df.iloc[:,0].eq(df.one).all()

Output: True

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns=['one', 'two'])

res1 = df.iloc[:,0].equals(df.one)
print(res1)#True

res2 = (df.iloc[:,0] == df.one).all()
print(res2)#True

